# Extra character when reading a file. C++

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, ifstream, qtcore

I'm writing two programs that communicate by reading files which the other one writes.

My problem is that when the other program is reading a file created by the first program it outputs a weird character at the end of the last data. This only happens seemingly at random, as adding data to the textfile can result in a normal output.

I'm utilizing C++ and Qt4. This is the part of program 1:

```
std::ofstream idxfile_new;
QString idxtext;
std::string fname2="some_textfile.txt";    //Imported from a file browser in the real code.
idxfile_new.open (fname2.c_str(), std::ios::out);
idxtext = ui->indexBrowser->toPlainText(); //Grabs data from a dialog of the GUI.
                                           //See 'some_textfile.txt' below
idxfile_new<<idxtext.toStdString();
idxfile_new.clear();
idxfile_new.close();
```

some_textfile.txt:

```
3714.1 3715.1 3716.1 3717.1 3719.1 3739.1 3734.1 3738.1 3562.1 3563.1 3623.1
```

part of program 2:

```
std::string indexfile = "some_textfile.txt";    //Imported from file browser in the real code
std::ifstream file;
std::string sub;
file.open(indexfile.c_str(), std::ios::in);
while(file>>sub)
{
    cerr<<sub<<"\n";    //Stores values in an array in the real code
}
```

This outputs:

```
3714.1
3715.1
3716.1
3717.1
3719.1
3739.1
3734.1
3738.1
3562.1
3563.1
3623.1�
```

If I add more data it works at times. Sometimes it can output data such as

```
3592.�
```

or

```
359�
```

at the end. So it is not consistent in reading the whole data either. At first I figured it wasn't reading the eof properly, and I have read and tried many solutions to similar problems but can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: Are both programs accessing the file concurrently (simultaneously)?

Comment: Why are you using `c_str` when printing or writing to the output file? Streams can handle `std::string` directly.

Comment: How do the programs synchronize access to the file?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo The program never accesses the file simultaneously.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My bad. I tried that just in case, in an attempt to solve it.

Comment: If you're using Qt and want to communicate between different programs, check out the `QSharedMemory` class. http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qsharedmemory.html

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA The first programs checks data values and save them to a file, followed by closing the file. After this is done, the first program calls the system() to execute the other program, which then opens the file. (and yes I'm aware of system() being a bad practice)

Comment: if you have QT why not use the QFile class wrapped in a QDataStream for the output

Comment: You should investigate the single steps instead of debugging everything together.  1. What's written to the file? Is the funny character in the file or appended in program 2? 2. What is the funny character? Check with a hex editor.

Comment: Also, could it be that you mix up clear() and flush()? clear() seems, wrong, try to omit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help!

I managed to solve the problem by myself this morning.
For anyone with the same problem I will post my solution.
The problem was the UTF-8 encoding when creating the file. Here's my solution:

Part of program 1:

```
std::ofstream idxfile_new;
QString idxtext;
std::string fname2="some_textfile.txt";
idxfile_new.open (fname2.c_str(), std::ios::out);
idxtext = ui->indexBrowser->toPlainText(); 

QByteArray qstr = idxtext.toUtf8(); //Enables Utf8 encoding
idxfile_new<<qstr.data();
idxfile_new.clear();
idxfile_new.close();
```

The other program is left unchanged.
A hex converter displayed the extra character as 'ef bf bd', which is due to the replacement character U+FFFD that replace invalid bytes when encoding to Utf8.